# Equals object criteria query

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

If I have two domain classes like this:

```
class Company{
    string Name
    string address
}

class User {
    string firstName
    string lastName
    Company company
}
```

How can I get all the users from company named Google using criteria query? Something like this:

```
def company = Company.findByName("Google")

def c = User.createCriteria()
def usersByCompany = c.list {
    eq("company", company)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a block inside your closure to filter any field in the Company:

```
def usersOfGoogle = User.createCriteria().list() {
    company {
      eq('name', 'Google')
    }
}
```

I just don't remember if it works only for relationships (belongsTo & hasMany), maybe you will need to change your domain class:

```
class User {
  static belongsTo = [company : Company]
}
```